# Stop interval when value==num?

Tags: javascript, intervals

My code having some problem. I only know how to make the stop function within a button.

Is there a way that we can make the stopInterval or clearInterval function to be implemented in the if...else checking function?

for e.g.:

```
if (theValue ==5){
   clearInterval;
}
```

Below is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/qHL8Z/52/

Answer (score 1):

change `var value = value + 1;` to `value = value + 1;`

Comment: hi, my question is .... is there a way to check the number if is equal to 5 and it will clear the interval and stop by itself ....

Comment: `$("#start").click(function() {
    var initial = $("#input").val();
    if (timer !== null) return;

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        value = value + 1;
        $("#input").val(value);
        if (parseInt(value) === parseInt(initial)) {
            $("#stop").trigger('click');
        }
    },
    interval);
});`

Comment: @rt2800 Please update your answer rather than posting blocks of code in the comments :)